# Object Oriented Programming : Initiating ab object in a GUI

Tags: c++, qt, oop, user-interface

I'm new to OO based programming, so a silly question:

I've created a class called **algorithmObject**. Basically, it has a bunch of functions associated with it.

I've created a QT GUI and I want to create a public object of type algorithmObject, since I want to be able to access the member functions in various onClick events.

So in my **GUI.h** file, I have:

```
public:

algorithmObject Object1;
```

In my **GUI.cpp** file, I'm trying to initialize it by:

```
 Object1 = algorithmObject();
```

I'm using MS VS 2010 and I get a compiler error:

error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
error C2065: 'Object1' : undeclared identifier

If I don't include :

```
Object1 = algorithmObject();
```

in my GUI.cpp file and just hope for the GUI constructor to create the object for me, I get the same error.

I guess, I am not initializing my object correctly in the .cpp file somehow. Can someone suggest what is the right process?

My algorithmObject files are outlined below:

**algorithmObject.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class algorithmObject 
{

public:

algorithmObject (void);
~algorithmObject (void);

void function1 (int parameter);
void function2 ();
}
```

**algorithmObject.cpp**

```
#include "algorithmObject.h"

algorithmObject::algorithmObject(void)
{
}

void algorithmObject::function1(int parameter)
{
//do something
}

void algorithmObject::function2()
{
//do something
}

algorithmObject::~algorithmObject(void)
{
}
```

If I however, don't include any definition in the GUI.h file and just define my algorithmObject within a single function in the GUI (algorithmObject Object1;) , I am able to correctly access the functionality of my class. But the problem is that the object is local to that function and I cannot access it from any other functions of the GUI.cpp file which is extremely crucial for me ...

Comment: Are you including algorithmObject.h in gui.h?

Comment: Whoops nice catch Jerry. I was including it in GUI.cpp :(. Can you please post this as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `algorithmObject.h` in `gui.h`, so by the time the compiler sees the code that tries to use an `algorithmObject`, it's already seen the declaration for the `algorithmObject` class.

It's *possible* to avoid this by always including `algorithmObject.h` in the source file *before* you try to use it, so you'd need to have:

```
#include "algorithmObject.h"
#include "gui.h"
```

Although this was fairly standard practice in a lot of C for a long time, I (personally) consider it fairly error-prone and fragile, so I generally prefer that if a header depends on other headers, it includes them itself, so there are no prerequisites to meet when including it in a source file.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation! :)